# Google Calendar Events created in Browser NOT visible in Android Application

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am writing an Android Application based around a Calendar. (I am using `Caldroid` library)

I have created a private Google calendar from within my web browser.

I can access this calendar within my Android application.

I can create calendar events from within my Android application and they are visible (after some time delay for synching) within my chrome browser calendar view.

However when I create calendar events with the browser, they are NEVER visible within my android application.

What have I missed in the Calendar docs?

... and Yes, i have the correct permissions set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue I needed to change my settings within the Android Google Calendar application.

Once I requested the android google calendar application synched with my private calendar all the events became visible.

Should this have been obvious to me?